# How to clean html entities out of blog post preview - Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am continuing my implementation of a blog app and i am creating posts using markdown (redcarpet gem).

In my test post however i have this code

```
#This is a test post

`<p> your paragraph text here </p>`
```

written in markdown.

and in my post view i have this

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><%= link_to post.title, blog_post_path(post) %></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <%= truncate(strip_tags(post.html), length: 80) %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

the thing is that while i want to strip html tags converted from markdown to html, i have html entities in the place of symbols <,> thus i get the following output

```
This is a test post &lt;p&gt; your paragraph text here &lt;/p&gt;
```

is there a workaround?i would for the <,> symbols to stay in this case or i should just have some introduction with normal characters only.

Also a second question: is there a way to target what part of the post i show in the preview?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? There was a bug with `strip_tags` transforming special characters into html entities with a recent version of Rails.

Comment: i am using 4.2.1 actually. is that bug inside this version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 4.2 introduced new implementations of HTML sanitizer methods (one of which is the `strip_tags` helper). Where once, HTML markup was removed via regular expression, Rails 4.2 achieves the same thing by using Nokogiri (by way of Loofah) under the covers.

It would seem that some backwards compatibility was lost, since `strip_tags` [seems to behave differently under Rails 4.2](https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer/issues/28) than with previous versions, so the workaround is to use the `sanitize` helper, rather than `strip_tags`.

Instead of:

```
<%= truncate(strip_tags(post.html), length: 80) %>
```

use:

```
<%= truncate(sanitize(post.html), length: 80) %>
```

The sanitize helper should be using the WhiteListSanitizer, but if it doesn't work, you can try to invoke the specific method directly using:

```
<%= truncate(Rails::Html::WhiteListSanitizer.new.sanitize(post.html), length: 80) %>
```